# Explain $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

Tags: probability

I know that there are $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ possibilities for drawing k balls from a jar containing n possible ones, whilst replacing them after each draw and disregarding order. Unfortunately, I still have difficulties actually arriving at that result on my own and the textbook by Blitzstein / Hwang is not very helpful either.

Hence, can somebody please: 
1) Explain how one is to arrive at that,
2) Prove that,
3) Direct me to a textbooks that would explain/prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: Do you mind spending just 10 minutes on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ_32wAgV08)?

Answer (score 2):

You actually mean that you are picking $k$ balls from $n$ **types** of balls.
Imagine instead that you are allowed to choose a total of $k$ candies from $n$ types of candies.

For each of the $n$ types, go on saying **yes** until you don't want any more, and then say **no** and move on to the next type.

Of course, you may say **no** straight away to any type if you don't want it, and you don't need to say **no** after the $n{th}$ because there is no next type.

So there will be $k$ of **yes** and  $(n-1)$ of **no** whichever way you choose, and the only decision you need to take is where to place the **yes's** in the sequence of $n+k-1$ responses,

thus # of choices $=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

---

I hope you can now see that in the usual "stars and bars" explanation:

$\Large\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast\ast\ast$

The "stars" stand for the $k$ **yes's**, and the "bars" for the $n-1$ **no's**